# Cómo puedo hacer una función en la cual dada una lista y un elemento, me regrese el numero de veces que se repite el elemento-no puede usar in e index

Tags: python

Este es mi código pero a la hora de correr el programa me indica que la palabra que pongo como elemento no esta definida

```
def cuentaElem(lista,elem):
    cont = 0
    for x in lista:
        if x == elem:
            cont += 1
    return cont
```

Answer (score 0):

acabo de probar tu código y no veo ningún error.

Lo más probable es que el error este en el argumento que le estas pasando a la función `cuentaElem`.

Por ejemplo

```
cuentaElem(["ej1", "ej2", "ej1"], ej1)
```

Como puedes ver estoy pasando un valor que no esta definido antes de llamar la función generando un error.

---

```
elem = "ej1"
cuentaElem(["ej1", "ej2", "ej1"], elem)
```

En este segundo ejemplo el argumento con el cual llamo a la función esta definido por lo cual no genera un error

**También puedes llamar a la función pasando directamente el argumento

```
cuentaElem(["ej1", "ej2", "ej1"], "ej1")
```

---

Teniendo en cuenta el titulo de tu pregunta

> No puede usar in e index

Modificaria tu función de la siguiente manera

```
def cuentaElem(lista,elem): 
    return lista.count(elem)
```

Comment: gracias si me funciono con el lista.count

Comment: @DiegoSebastiánÁvilaHurtado no olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) esta respuesta.